# Celery: Unregistered Task

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I have tried to follow the [Celery tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html). I am using celery version 4.1.0

```
|-module
  |-tasks
    |-__init__.py
    |-tasks.py
```

The contents of `__init__.py` is empty. I have created a file called tasks.py inside tasks directory.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("tasks", broker="redis://localhost:6379/0", backend="redis://localhost:6379/0")


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I have started the Redis server and in another terminal window I have started the celery worker server with:

```
celery worker -A module.tasks.tasks -l info -P eventlet
```

To run the task:

```
$ python
>>> from tasks import add
>>> add.delay(1, 1)
```

Inside the server worker terminal window I get the following error:

```
[2018-03-21 13:46:48,859: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'module.tasks.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[1, 2], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (81b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Callu\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 561, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'module.tasks.tasks.add'
```

**UPDATE:**
If a change to the tasks directory and try to call the add function, it works. But say if I try to call the add function from another python file it outputs the same error message as before.

Comment: Please show the exact code you used to put the task on the queue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just run the python interpreter. Import the method and call it.

Answer (score 0):

To run now celery first make sure you are inside `module/tasks/` directory and then run celery by:

```
celery worker -A tasks -l info -P eventlet
```

Answer (score 0):

I start my celery like this:

```
python -m celery -A yourpackage #add your specific options here
```

The above means within your venv there must be a package installed called yourpackage. If you are not familiar with packaging your code google for phrase like `how to create setup.py` or similar. Once you have your package ready you can install it like this:

```
source /path/to/your/venv
cd /path/to/your/yourpackage
pip install -e .
```

At this stage celery will expect your settings file to be located within `celery.py` file. My `celery.py` looks like this:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(
    'yourpackagename',
    include=[
        'tasks.tasks.add',
    ]
)
app.config_from_object('yourpackagename.celeryconfig')
```

Now you need to create your `celeryconfig.py` file (it does not have to be called that way, and in fact probably you do not even have to do this that way); I use rabbitmq, so your values will look different

```
# Setup backend
BACKEND = 'amqp'
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost'
```

At this point your folders structure looks like this:

```
|-yourpackagename
  |-setup.py
  |-yourpackagename
    |-celery.py
    |-celeryconfig.py
    |-tasks
      |-__init__.py
      |-tasks.py
```